# Retrieving Additional Column Value Corresponding to Maximum Value in Spark SQL Window Function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with Spark SQL and a dataset containing columns Id, filedate, and exposure. I need assistance in formulating a Spark SQL query to identify, for each Id, the maximum exposure value within a specific window based on the filedate. Furthermore, I want to retrieve the filedate corresponding to that maximum exposure value within the defined window.

| Id | filedate | exposure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 257503 | 1/7/2022 | 500 |
| 257503 | 1/8/2022 | 845 |
| 257503 | 1/11/2022 | 1020 |
| 257503 | 1/21/2022 | 365 |
| 257503 | 1/22/2022 | 965 |
| 257503 | 1/27/2022 | 1115 |
| 257503 | 1/28/2022 | 2730 |
| 257503 | 1/29/2022 | 3595 |
| 257503 | 2/1/2022 | 3840 |

For each Id, I aim to find the maximum exposure within a window of, let's say, the previous 5 days based on the filedate. Additionally, I need to retrieve the filedate associated with that maximum exposure within the specified window.

Query:

SELECT Id,filedate,exposure, MAX(exposure) OVER ( PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(filedate) ASC  RANGE BETWEEN 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS peakExposure FROM exposures

Any insights or suggestions on how to structure this Spark SQL query would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Are you using azure databrbicks?

Comment: No, apache spark